# Represent the Maximal Domain of the Given Laws (Multivariable Inequalities)

Tags: calculus, inequality

So I have to represent the Maximal Domain of this law
$$ A = \{ x \in R^2 : x_1 < x_2 \} $$

My Idea was to take $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = y$. I then found $ y > x$ , so I made it an equation as $ y = x$ and sketched the line in a graph. I thought that the domain would have been the upper right corner; yet plugging some random numbers proves my idea wrong.

I am completely unsure that a graph is what the professor wants. The question for the exercise is exactly the title of this post.

What would your take be?

I have also do to the same for

$$B = \{ x \in R^2 : x^2_1 + x_2^2 < 4 \}$$

Thanks for your help! It would be very appreciated, I have been banging my head on these exercises for two days now.

(The subject is "Mathematical Methods for Economics" and the topic is optimization problems)

Answer (score 1):

The professor is using the common notation $(x_1,x_2)$ instead of $(x,y)$. It is often used since you can speak of the $k^{\textrm th}$ coordinate $x_k$ using the same notation for all coordinates. But I will address the question using $(x,y)$ since you seem more comfortable with that.

Your first shot was correct. It is the half-plane above the line $y=x$ (it doesn't include the bounding line since the inequality is strict).

You can often answer such questions by considering the corresponding equality, which usually describes the boundary. The boundary breaks the plane into various connected regions, and you then can test points within these regions to determine which regions satisfy the given inequality.

Note that if the inequality is not strict ("$\leq$" instead of "$<$"), then the boundary *is* included.

So for the second problem, the boundary is the curve $x^2+y^2=4$, a circle. The complementary regions are the interior of the circle (an open disk) and the exterior of the circle (plane with a hole in it). Points in the inner region satisfy the original inequality, as you can see that the test point $(0,0)$ does.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. I will analyze the first case: Let's say I have found out that the maximal domain is $y>x$ . If I rearrange it, I get $y -x > 0$. Yet, if I take $ x = -10$ and $ y = 0$ I get $ 10 > 0 $ that is an acceptable result. Yet looking at the graph, that result should not be part of the acceptable results of the function. This is something I cannot understand :(

Comment: The point $(-10,0)$ is in the region. Let's be sure you are thinking about the right region. The line $y=x$ is the diagonal line that runs from southwest to northeast, passing through the origin. The region of interest (above this line) includes the entire northwest quadrant (quadrant 2) and the upper halves of the southwest and northeast quadrants (quadrants 1 and 3). In particular, it includes the negative part of the horizontal axis (x-axis). So your point $(-10,0)$ is indeed in the region of interest, right?

Comment: Actually Perfect! Thank you a lot for your help!